# How to send email with attachment from form?

Tags: django

I've been trying different ways to send an attachment from a submitted form but I'm not able to get it right.

my model:

```
from django.db import models


class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField()
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from decouple import config
from .forms import ContactForm


def contact(request):
    contact_form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if contact_form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get("name")
            email = request.POST.get("email")
            subject = request.POST.get("subject")
            message = request.POST.get("message")
            upload = request.POST.get("upload")

            email_content= EmailMessage("Message from django-structure project",
                                        f"The user with name {name}, with the email {email},"
                                        f" write the following: \n Subject: {subject} \n File{upload} \n\n Message: {message}",
                                 "", [config('EMAIL_TO')], reply_to=[email])
            try:
                email_content.send()

                return redirect("/contact/?valid")

            except:
                return redirect("/contact/?invalid")

    return render(request, "contact.html", {"form": contact_form})
```

contact.html

```
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
     <div class="form-group">
    {% if "valid" in request.GET %}
        <p style="color: blue;">Information sent successfully </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="text-align: center;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table style="color: dark; margin:20px auto;">{{form.as_table}}</table>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" style="width: 150px;">

    </form>
</div>
```

When I submit the form, I receive the message but in the content of the File, just the following string:  "FleNone". (I have attached a pdf)

Comment: use the `attach_file` function of `EmailMessage`. here is the django code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/3119a6decab7788eca662b10e8c18351d20df212/django/core/mail/message.py#L318

Comment: What you trying to do does not work.. please refer the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/)